# Use of enthalpy of vaporisation for evaporation in a actively pumped vacuum

Tags: thermodynamics, vacuum

I have a question relating to non-equilibrium thermodynamics: specifically, lets say that I have a liquid being heated in vacuum (like a liquid iron for example that was being actively pumped by a set of vacuum pumps. If I wanted to quantify the required energy to evaporate this liquid, I would typically use the enthalpy of vaporization, $H_{vap}$, but given that the enthalpy is only defined in an equilibrium system, I am unsure if i can use this.

However, I have also seen work that suggests that using the enthalpy of vaporization as a measure of the change in internal energy required to remove a particle from the liquid. Is this correct, considering that pressure would not be well defined for an actively-pumped vacuum chamber?

Is the use of $H_{vap}$ correct for a system under vacuum?

Comment: Is the liquid boiling?

Comment: @ChetMiller we could use the argument here that it is at an elevated temperature so it has a non-zero vapor pressure, so yes it would be evaporating

Comment: @Chemomechanics Can you provide a detailed example of this please? I don't think the system is reversible here as we have an actively pumped vacuum so we cannot describe the system using equilibrium thermodymanics.

Comment: Chet describes [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/grandpa-chets-entropy-recipe/) (and in many Physics Stack Exchange answers) how one can replace an irreversible path with a reversible path to solve a problem using equilibrium thermodynamics.

Comment: Is there air in the head space?

Comment: @ChetMiller No, this is a model of an experimental setup that I am using and the internal pressure of vacuum chamber is around 1e-7 hPa so it is practically zero

Comment: @Chemomechanics Thank you, but the attached data deals with a closed system which is not the case here as we have mass flow in the form of evaporation out of the system

Comment: At that low a pressure, the liquid is boiling.  You use the heat of vaporization at the applied vacuum pressure.